# My phone isn’t able to receive incoming calls from my girlfriend’s phone but can make outgoing calls to it

Tags: iphone

Whenever my girlfriend calls my phone, she gets the same message you would get if you were to call someone who’s blocked you, and the call doesn’t go through. Although this happens, we’re still able to exchange texts, FaceTime each other, and I can call her. For the time being, whenever she needs to call me, she uses FaceTime audio.

I’m using an iPhone 11 running iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of things you could try:

1. Check your settings Phone > Silence Unknown Caller - disable this if enabled.
2. Type her number out on the dial pad to see if her number is saved as another contact on your phone that was previously blocked.
3. Try resetting call blocking software like TrueCaller
4. Try saving her number under a new contact after removing everything that showed up on Step 2 and adding the new number to favourites.